# Creating an object with 4 button on javascript

Tags: javascript, object, button

I created an object on `js` with 4 buttons, but it's not showing,

this is my code:

```
function Keyboard() {
    this.plus = document.createElement("input");
    this.plus.type = "submit";
    this.plus.value = "A";
    this.minus = document.createElement("input");
    this.minus.type = "submit";
    this.minus.value = "B";
    this.multi = document.createElement("input");
    this.multi.type = "submit";
    this.multi.value = "C";
    this.divide = document.createElement("input");
    this.divide.type = "submit";
    this.divide.value = "D";

}
var k = new Keyboard();
document.body.appendChild(k);
```

I will add the onClick later, but why is this not showing?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at your console for errors?

Comment: what is 'k' containing?console and show?

Comment: there are no errors on my console. this is what k is containg. maybe i'm not creating an object correctly i'm not sure i'm fairly new to js

Comment: From what i can tell hes just instantiating a new instance of the class. but I think you forgot that the properties of the class arent being called. you are just calling the whole class, you have to get each button with dot notation in your case an example `k.plus` will out put the button for `A`

Comment: ok I think I figured it out.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Keyboard` constructs a simple JavaScript object with 4 properties, but not a DOM object. Later, you try to append a simple JavaScript object to your document.

**First**, you need to create DOM element using `document.createElement`.
**Second**, you don't need `new` keyword here at all.
**Third**, you don't need to set subitems as properties. You append them to a parent object, and it is enough.

Try the following code:

```js
function CreateKeyboard() {
  var t = document.createElement("div");

  var plus = document.createElement("input");
  plus.type = "submit";
  plus.value = "A";
  t.appendChild(plus);

  var minus = document.createElement("input");
  minus.type = "submit";
  minus.value = "B";
  t.appendChild(minus);

  var multi = document.createElement("input");
  multi.type = "submit";
  multi.value = "C";
  t.appendChild(multi);

  var divide = document.createElement("input");
  divide.type = "submit";
  divide.value = "D";
  t.appendChild(divide);

  return t;
}

document.body.appendChild(CreateKeyboard());
```

By the way, you can avoid code repetition. For example, by utilizing `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
function CreateKeyboard() {
  var t = document.createElement("div");

  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].forEach(function(l) {
      var elem = document.createElement("input");
      elem.type = "submit";
      elem.value = l;
      t.appendChild(elem);
  });

  return t;
}

document.body.appendChild(CreateKeyboard());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function createSubmitButton(val) {
        var el = document.createElement("input");
        el.type = "submit";
        el.value = val;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
    createSubmitButton("A");
    createSubmitButton("B");
    createSubmitButton("C");
    createSubmitButton("D");
    </script>
```

Make sure you place the script tag at the bottom of the html code, right before the ending body tag.

Answer (score 0):

k is not type of Node. Append only Node elements you have created.

```
var k = new Keyboard();
document.body.appendChild(k.plus);
document.body.appendChild(k.minus);
document.body.appendChild(k.multi);
document.body.appendChild(k.divide);
```